# How to package and deploy Microsoft Edge Browser extension to Windows Store?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

How to package and deploy Microsoft Edge Browser Extension to marketplace?
I reference sample package and develop the Edge extension include below files

- README.MD
- manifest.json
- background.html
- css folder
- js folder
- icons folder

And I tested from Edge load extension folder.
But I don't know how to package and deploy to Microsoft marketplace.
Someone can advise me?

Answer (score 2):

### Updated (12/19/2016):

Microsoft Edge team has published the [packaging documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/guides/packaging/).

### Previous:

According to [Building, Testing and Deploying a Browser Extension in Microsoft Edge](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/New-Zealand-2016/M357), which is a session in [Microsoft Ignite NZ](https://msignite.nz/), Microsoft Edge team has worked with [Manifoldjs](http://manifoldjs.com/) to bring support of generating Edge extension appx package. **You could follow the [ReadMe of Manifoldjs](https://github.com/manifoldjs/manifoldjs-edgeextension) to generate an appx package for Microsoft Edge extensions.**

And as it states in above session, Microsoft Edge isn't accepting public submissions to the store at this time, if you're interested in deploying your extensions to the Windows Store, please consider submitting a request to https://aka.ms/extension-request to be considered for a future update.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is trying to use manifoldjs or pwabuilder and are having issues, here is a work around.

*First, just don't.*

```
manifoldjs -l debug -p edgeextension -m <MANIFEST-LOCATION>.json
```

Update generated appxmanifest.xml.  Values are found in partner center.

```
    <Identity 
        Name="<NAME>" 
        Publisher="<PUBLISHER>" 
        Version="0.1.0.0" /> <!-- UPDATE IDENTITY -->
```

```
    <Properties> 
        <DisplayName>DISPLAY-NAME</DisplayName> 
        <PublisherDisplayName>PUBLISHER-NAME</PublisherDisplayName> <!-- UPDATE PUBLISHER DISPLAY NAME -->
        <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo> 
    </Properties>
```

Update logos found in Assets folder.

Run CMD as admin, run command below

```
MakeAppx pack /d <MANIFEST FOLDER PATH> /p <APPX LOCATION>

ex: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\makeappx.exe" pack /d "manifest" /p "package\mypackage.appx"
```

I hope this helps someone.